# Getting "KeyError: not found in axis" when trying to drop a column from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried both:

```
df = df.copy() 
df.drop([' SG'], axis = 1)
```

AND

```
df = df.copy() 
df.drop(['SG '], axis = 1)
```

SG is the column on my data frame that I'm trying to drop.

```
KeyError: "['SG'] not found in axis"
```

This is what my data looks like, see on attached image

[image: Image:]

Comment: You might have a (or more) whitespace character in your column name of your dataframe. Tell us the exact output of `df.columns`. Otherwise, you might have multi-index columns. In that case, tell us what `df.info()` shows.

Comment: @Firelord, I thought when I put the command leaving space before SG and also attempted to put it after SG df = df.copy() df.drop(['SG '], axis = 1) AND df = df.copy() df.drop([' SG'], axis = 1) that would help with white space character, clearly it's not helping. You gave me two things to check, df.columns & df.info(), after trying these, I realized that I only get this error when I run the cell twice. I I click run once, "SG" column gets removed but as soon as I click again, the error comes, I guess at this stage it's just telling me indeed "SG" is not there.

Answer (score 1):

`df.drop(['SG'], axis=1)` doesn't change the dataframe inplace.

instead you need to override the DataFrame by doing this below.

```
df = df.drop(['SG'], axis=1)
```

Or by including the argument `inplace=True` Like this:

```
df.drop(['SG'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Either option should work fine.
I'd recommend using the first option it will be more error prone for the future.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be this. OP reported this error. `KeyError: "['SG'] not found in axis"`. Whether you do drop inplace or not should not report this error unless the column doesn't really exist.

Comment: How do you construct your dataframe?

Comment: I'm not OP. That question should be addressed to OP. :)

Comment: ahh alright then.

Comment: I assume the DataFrame is probably incorrect in some way or the axis is just 0 and not 1. I tried it myself works just fine.

Comment: I have asked OP for some clarification in the comments. Hopefully, that should sort things out.

Comment: @Roy, thanks for the suggestion, there's definitely something wrong I'm doing here because, after seemingly resolved the issue of dropping "SG", when I put the dependent/ independent variables, I now get a new error as below:

    df.columns
    Index(['R', 'pH'], dtype='object')
    n=6
    x = df.drop("pH")
    y = df.drop("pH",1)
    df.head(n=6) then the error comes as: KeyError: "['pH'] not found in axis"